# How to capture Java traffic with Fiddler2 WITHOUT setting a proxy?

Tags: java, proxy, fiddler

Fiddler2 can sniff browser traffic without setting a proxy in it. So it should be possible to capture Java traffic without setting proxy too.

How to do that?

Comment: it sets the browser proxy automatically for you.

Answer (score 1):

When it starts, Fiddler adjusts the system proxy setting to point to itself, and it reverts this setting when it exits. For Java, you can typically specify the desired proxy settings on the `javaw` command line.

Some JVM implementations offer an option to adopt the environment's proxy settings automatically; you might find this option in the Java Control Panel. If not, you should consider asking `How can I configure Java to use the system proxy automatically` over on SuperUser.